# What are the proper uses of the various "Sign-in" terminologies?

Tags: jargon, terminology

What are the preferred use cases for the following sets of terms:

1. Log in / Log out
2. Log on / Log off
3. Sign in / Sign out
4. Sign on / Sign off

From what I can guess, "Logging in" should be used for a long-lived session (like a website), whereas "Sign in" should be for something that you will be attending to (like IM or a financial transaction).

I'm a little fuzzy here...

Comment: You might be interested in http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/1080/using-sign-in-vs-using-log-in and http://ui.stackexchange.com/questions/626/exit-or-log-out-to-leave-your-session

Answer (score 2):

I've always used Login/Logout without the space.   I notice that Microsoft is preferential to Sign in/Sign out.

Comment: Login/Logout are nouns. Add the space and they become verbs.

Comment: @Mark H +1 for the eagle eye observation. Most of us couldn't have cared less :)

Comment: Stack Exchange, Google, Facebook and Twitter, Flickr and Yahoo all use verbs -- with the space.

Answer (score 2):

These are all a matter of style (I prefer those with in/out over on/off).

Just choose one pair and make sure you use them consistently, and definitely don't mix your terms like `Log on / Sign out`.

Answer (score 2):

I forget where I read it, I think it was the Rails company **Thoughtbot** but the basic idea was to use "Sign" for everything so that there are three actions always:

1. Sign In
2. Sign Out
3. Sign Up

This nomenclature makes sense because the basis for authentication is a logbook, so you "sign in" when you enter and "sign out" when you leave.

Answer (score 0):

There *isn't* a "proper use." It's all preference. They're all synonyms, as far as the Web At Large is concerned.

Answer (score 0):

SO sites goes with Log in and Log out! So it could a standard way!

Answer (score 0):

They are all similar, occasionally you might even see Enter / Exit or Start / Stop or ...

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft has very well defined guidlines to this... For anyone w/ Safari, you can follow along in "Framework Design Guidlines - Conventions, Idioms, and Patterns for reusable .Net libraries"

Table 3-2 lists the "Microsofty" way (for what it's worth):

Use **Log Off** not Log Out

Use **Log On** not Log In

Use **Sign In** and **Sign Out** not Log On and Log Off

There are about 20 conventions listed and they are listed for the sake of consistency...

I always preferred "Sign In" over "Log On", but it's just personal choice to me...

Answer (score -1):

Which one sounds most natural?

```
What's your login detail?
What's your logon detail?
What's your sign in detail?
What's your sign on detail?
```

That's sufficient for me to chose one.

Comment: Do you mean `What are` instead of `What is`?

Comment: @Fosco: login detail can be singular if you think of it as a username/password pair, or it can be plural if you think of it as a bunch of authentication information. It doesn't really matter for my main point, though I corrected it anyway.